# IronPython Linq Lambda Issue

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I am using Linq in a simple IronPython script to perform a lookup against an entity framework database context:

```
import clr
import System

clr.AddReference('Common')
clr.AddReference('System.Core')
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)

from Common import Message

db = Lib.Data.db #Lib passed into environment

#RequestMessage passed into environment
username = RequestMessage.Data.Username
password = RequestMessage.Data.Password

#outputs the username as expected
System.Console.WriteLine(username)

#always returns null
users = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(lambda x: x.Username == username)

#returns expected data
users = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(lambda x: x.Username == 'someuser')
```

The above code works just fine if I substitute `username` for a hardcoded string containing an actual username in the database. When i use the variable itself, the expression always evaluates to null/None.

Comment: I suspect but don't have the references to make it a full answer that username(the variable) ends up as a dynamic on the c# and since it is reference equality it doesn't match. Using `.Eqauls` may solve the problem.

Comment: @Sign: That's a good guess, but bear in mind that `db.Users` is backed Entity Framework, so it's trying to convert the expression to SQL. It may have something to do with the pythonic type of the `username` variable, but it's probably not related to the `==` operator specifically.

Comment: @Sign is correct. I tried the following code: ```db.Users.FirstOrDefault(lambda x:x.Username.Equals(username.ToString()))``` and it successfully returned the data. Do you guys know of a way to avoid requiring the ToString() or is that something I'm going to have to deal with when working with DLR?

Comment: @Bob did you try it with just .Equals?

Comment: Yes it had the same issue. I have to cast it to the required type for the comparison to succeed.